# iphone popviewcontoller will not able to push again

Tags: objective-c

I have two view controllers when i do

> [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

from second view to first view , not able to navigate again  to the same view , tried using window.navigation but not working for me

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem with some code.

Comment: this is second view code from here i can pop back ,
if (foundResponse)
    {
        if( [deleteBeneficiary.deactivateBeneficiary caseInsensitiveCompare:@"SUCCESS"] == NSOrderedSame )
        {
             
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          
            
        }
    }

Comment: for navigating again
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        AddNewPayeeView * objAddnew = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNewPayeeID"];
        
       
        
        if(isFromSearch)
        {
            objAddnew.beneficiaryID=((Beneficiaries *)[dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).beneficiaryID;
            objAddnew.beneficiaryName= ((Beneficiaries *)[dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).beneficiaryName;
           
        }

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` the initial view controller must be embedded inside a navigation controller , and the one you want to make the pop from is pushed inside the stack